# Logistic regression with 2 predictive variables

Tags: logistic, spss, interaction, contrasts

I need some advice for choosing the correct model. I have 3 binary variables: Risk (0 = the person doesn't take financial risks, 1 = the person takes financial risks), gender (0 = female, 1 = male), and type of person (type 0 vs. type 1). The types are well defined, but for me, it's a binary variable for comparison.
The questions of interest are: 1. Do type 0 males take more risks than females (of any type)? 2. Does type 0 males takes more risks than type 1 males? 3. Same like question 2, just for females.

Which model should I use? I thought maybe logistic regression, with interaction and perhaps contrasts, but I am not sure. Could you please advice me on which model is most appropriate? I will be using SPSS, so if contrasts are required, I would appreciate a tip on how to do it there.

Comment: You have just 8 possible combinations of features - does a simple table of frequencies of those combinations not give you the desired information?

Comment: Frequencies are very informative, but I do need something confirmatory, a model or a test, with p-values.